# Which hardware is used by buffer

Tags: memory, cache, buffer, free

I know that the cache is used to store data so that future requests for that data can be served faster. Normally we have three level cache: L1, L2 and L3 in the current computer architecture. We can see the cache hardware.

[image]

Also, I've heard about the buffer, which is used to arrange the IO stream. But I don't know which hardware is used by the buffer. Is it simply the memory?

For example, in Linux system, `free -m` can show me the usage of cache/buff:

[image]

If I'm right, the `buff/cache` shows the size of cache + the size of buffer. So the size of cache comes from the L1, L2 and L3 cache, right? But what about the size of buffer? Which hardware is used by the buffer?

Comment: None of your last paragraph is correct.

Comment: "Cache" is used for lots of different components. `free` shows you the **disk** cache, which is just normal RAM. Your picture shows **CPU** cache. There are hundreds of other kinds of caches in various application programs (and in the kernel as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing two concepts here. The L1/2/3 caches are managed by the processor (that is, the hardware and its firmware/[microcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode)) itself, the kernel (usually) has no control over them. The cache and buffer that `free` is referring to are managed by the kernel, and are located in RAM. However parts of it *may* be found in the processor caches, but that doesn't matter for the OS functionality.